# How to change the background of a cell in excel, by using a formula, no Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, colors, conditional-formatting

I have a column with numbers 0 to 100 and I want to change the background colour of the next column according to those values
with 0 as red, and 100 as normal green
and as the number gets higher, the colour fades from red to light red, to white in 50 and then, light green to green in 100

The question is how do I do that, without using conditional formatting

I was trying to use ColourIndex, as

```
=Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255,0,0)
```

but the function is not working, and I do not want to use conditional formatting

Any ideas?

Comment: Removed CSS tag, since the question is not about CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use conditional formatting, your only other avenue is VBA. But this can easily be done with **ONE SINGLE** conditional format applied to the range of 100 cells.

If you want to format the column to the right of the original values, use a formula to pull the values from the column to the left, then apply a color scale conditional format to the target column.

Set a custom number format of `;;;` to hide the numbers in the formatted column.

[image]

Answering your question as stated in your title (How to change the background of a cell in excel, by using a formula, no Conditional Formatting) - You can't. Not with a worksheet formula.

Comment: I know, but how do you do it in VBA then? (any descriptive tutorial like link), are you sure there is no formula to modify the background of a cell?

Comment: Any reason you WANT to reinvent the wheel and use VBA instead of three clicks on the user interface? With VBA you need a change event. Which event exactly will depend on your situation. We don't have enough information to answer that.

Comment: Certainly I have a reason, I WANT to know whether is possible to use a formula instead of conditional formatting. This is not about the easy way of doing something but instead on how to do it differently

Comment: I edited my answer. That provides the answer to your question as asked, even if the answer is "it can't be done". So please mark the answer.

Comment: I will wait for more people to see this question, maybe someone out there has another method, idea, link, anyway thank you for your reply

Comment: It's ok, no need to be so upset/impatient about this, relax, it is just a question

Comment: One obvious reason you might want to avoid conditional formatting is that conditional formatting is volatile.  For very large and/or very complex files, conditional formatting can be incredibly time-expensive.

Comment: @WeylinPiegorsch That is true, but formatting applied with VBA will then in turn become outdated if the data changes, AND it is much slower to update the cell formatting of a sheet using VBA compared to conditional formatting.